# How do I import java classes in clojure?

Tags: java, clojure

I am aware of this experiment with using java classes in clojure.
https://github.com/bigos/JavaApplication3/blob/master/clojure/responder/src/jac/responder.clj

But how do I use java classes in Clojure where there are multiple files in several folders?

The file is in folder like

> classes/sal/reports/Report.class

How do I import such file for use in Clojure?

I have tried to copy the file to classes folder on clojure side and added that folder fo deps.edn path. the I tried to import it like this
`(:import (sal.reports Report)`)
but that did not work.

## slight progress

I have modified deps.edn file

```
:paths ["src" "resources" "../reportgenerator/build/web/WEB-INF/classes"
```

and my import looks like

```
 (:import (sal.reports Report)
```

I have given up on copying java classes and pointed deps.edn to use IDE's classes folder.

I no longer get class not found errors related to the Report class.
And loading the code in repl works.

Now when I try to run
(. Report  (cjurestring))

I get class not found error that relates to a jar that sits in legacy project lib folder.

Caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfTemplate

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? Please be specific. Have you added `classes` to your classpath? Please also share the project structure and the build tool you are using.

Comment: Is the .jar file in your classpath?

Comment: @cfrick how do I add it?

Comment: https://clojure.org/guides/deps_and_cli#local_jar - yet without knowing the full extend what you are after, this might just be quite tiresome to manage more than just a few jars like that. From what there is to extrapolate from your question, you have some reportgenerator, that is built as a war file to be deployed in some application server and you want to re-use stuff from within that?

Comment: @cfrick You are correct. And tthe lib folder has only 15 jar files. I do not understand the example in your link. Particularly the What/ever part :     what/ever {:local/root "../reportgenerator/lib/openpdf-1.3.23.jar"}   ---- I can open the openpdf jar and I can see the classes inside, but the documentation does not give me idea how to write the first what/ever part.

Comment: another comment. I want to use Clojure to write a jar file that will be part of that legacy java project.

Comment: You put a namespaced symbol by any name (assuming this here, because i am not a deps.end user myself) as key and a map as described in the lin into your deps - so what you wrote there is pretty much, what I'd expect to work.

Comment: Then I'd look into clojure plugins for gradle.

Comment: What build system are you using for your Java program? An entry in `:deps` in Clojure's `deps.edn` file is roughly analogous to a `<dependencies>` entry in Maven's `pom.xml` and a `dependencies` entry in Gradle's `build.gradle`. This includes inferring all the transitive dependencies.